# Unique 4 digit number

Tags: plugins

I need a feature on my site that can either generate a unique 4 digit number, or a field where you can choose your own 4 digit number. It is very important that no one can have the same number. Also i need to store the numbers that have been generated. Any idea how i could build something like this? Any plugins? I have used WPForms plugin to store data from filled forms, but it does not have a "unique" field feature.

Comment: What is the issue you're currently running into? This sounds like you're asking for someone to build this for you which runs under the "Too Broad" spectrum of closure votes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For unique 4 digit number, the following code work fine

```
function unique_number($length=10) {

   $string = '';
   // You can define your own characters here.
   $characters = "0123456789";

   for ($p = 0; $p < $length; $p++) {
       $string .= $characters[mt_rand(0, strlen($characters)-1)];
   }

   return $string;
}

print unique_number(4);
```

Every plugin has extended capability to change the default value of field or form. You should need to know how this work.

I am giving you the example for ACF custom fields.

```
//for acf
function my_acf_load_field( $field ) {

     $rand = unique_number(4);
     $field['default_value'] = $rand;
     return $field;

}

add_filter('acf/load_field/name=your_field_name', 'my_acf_load_field');
```

Comment: +1 for the effort, but this will not create "unique" numbers, it'll only create random numbers. To create unique numbers, you must save them in database & then compare to make sure they are unique. Also, don't forget the limit of 4 digit numbers, with maximum 9999, it's not possible to create unique numbers afterwards. Since the OP is not asking for randomness, perhaps an auto increment in the DB is better in this case.